# Bash script colored output to browser with php

Tags: php, bash

I have a php file which currently puts in the browser the output of a bash script:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$cmd = "./bash_script.sh";

$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),
  2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());

echo '<pre>';
if (is_resource($process)) {
  while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
    print $s;
  }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, in CLI the output of my bash_script.sh is colored formatted but in the browser output there is no formatting and colors are not visible.

I have tried the following simple example with command `ls --color`:

```
<?php
$cmd = "ls --color";
$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),
  2 => array("pipe", "w")
);
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo '<pre>';
if (is_resource($process)) {
  while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
  print $s;
  }
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And its output comes with color codes (or at least I believe so), that is:

> [01;34mFolder1[0m
>
> [01;34mFolder2[0m
>
> [01;34mFolder3[0m
>
> [01;32mFile1[0m
>
> [01;34mFolder4[0m

However, with my script, those color codes don't appear.

Is it possible to print the same colored output I get in CLI to the browser?

Comment: are you able to control how the output is sent from `bash_script.sh`?

Comment: @Dharma I can modify bash_script.sh but not its formatted output since it makes use of another tool which provides the colors

Answer (score 1):

Since there are color formats in the output, you could set a translations table that converts between the cli and php.

A **quick-n-dirty** example:

1. Define translations
   `$colors = ['[01;32m' => '<span style="color:green">', …, '[0m' => '</span>']`
2. Then replace
   `str_replace(array_keys($colors), array_values($colors))`

**NOTE**: usually color formats are defined in this form `\e[32mHello world`, where `\e` is a shortand for ESCAPE char, so see case by case forms of defining a color format.

**Tool way**: you might also try if this works fine: [aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha), an **Ansi HTML Adapter**.

Comment: I think this could work in case of I have the output with the color codes (as in the example I put with `ls --color` command), however unfortunately my real script does not provide these color codes, so I won't be able to translate them :(

Comment: Just tried now, it works fine for the `ls --color` example but it doesn't work with my real script, I don't understand why because when I run it from CLI I get properly the html color codes. Since my bash_script.sh is actually an expect script, I'm afraid that it is not able to handle the colors properly...